# Add left and right margins or padding to custom v4.master (s4-bodyContainer)?

Tags: master-page, branding, custom-masterpage

How do I add margins/padding to the left and right of the master page while still retaining the scroll-bar on the right?

I don't want a fixed-width page - just scaling width, with left and right margins.

The issue I see is that some JavaScript hard-codes the inline width of the s4-bodyContainer. This throws out any margins/attempt that I attempt to add to my CSS (it overflows right).

I've tried a 100% width !important without any luck:

```
#s4-bodyContainer
{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px; 
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I general you will find all on my blog that needs to be done: http://www.n8d.at/blog/centered-fixed-width-design-in-sharepoint-2010-the-fast-way/

What you need to do is:

```
div.s4-title.s4-lp,
 body #s4-mainarea,
 #s4-topheader2,
 #s4-statusbarcontainer{
     margin: 50px;
     padding: 0px;
     float: none;
     background-image: none;
     background-color: white;
}
```

1) What you also nee to do is change:

```
<div id="s4-workspace">
```

to:

```
<div id="s4-workspace" class="s4-nosetwidth">
```

2)

```
<div id="s4-titlerow" class="s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle">
```

needs to be changed:

```
<div id="s4-titlerow" class="s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle s4-nosetwidth">
```

By setting the s4-nosetwidth class SharePoint won't add the javascripts to set the width of the page.
I haven't tried this out yet but is should work.

Comment: Thanks, I also had to use `.s4-pr { width: inherit; }
` to stop the ribbon row going too wide, but that might just be my master page.

Comment: To avoid issues with the pop-up dialogs, I removed their margins by using the same style as per the answer above using the `.ms-dialog` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Peter,

For this I usually take a table with three `<td>`, wrap the bodycontainer in the middle td so that even if its 100% it doesn't get outside the `<td>`...

and then first and last `<td>` to be used for spacing/left-right margins! give `width=50px` to these two td's